# MYSQL string and performance on Replace

Tags: mysql, performance, replace

I have say 10,000 records to Replace (most will be Insert, but there is need for Replace so I must use Replace) of a large table with dates, varchars, integers, etc. The table also has a primary key and several other indexes. I build an SQL string of rows to Replace. If performance is my only concern, what generally, is the optimum number of rows to insert at once? I assume it is not 1. Is it 10, 500, 1,000, etc at a time?

Does the length of the string matter for performance?

Comment: Put the values in a temporary table and load them from the temporary table.  That should be the fastest method.

Comment: I need this data in multiple scripts, for the entire user batch session that is running, so I am unclear how a temporary table helps. Thank you.

Comment: If you need them in the database for the entire batch session, then that makes a temporary table all the more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend 100-1000 at a time; that will run about 10 times as fast as one at a time.  Anything beyond 100-1000 is into "diminishing returns".  (That is, you won't get much more improvement.)

But...  There are other things of note.

`REPLACE` is `DELETE` (which might delete zero rows), plus `INSERT`.  This is slower than `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, which either `INSERTs` or changes whatever you say to change (which could be all the columns).

If you are using `AUTO_INCREMENT`... With `REPLACE` you are throwing away any existing ids and creating new ones.  In the long run, you *could* have a problem with running out of ids.

If you don't want to waste *any* `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids, let's talk further.

If replication is involved, 100 is better than 1000; let me know if you want to know why.

The length of the string is limited to `max_packet_length`, which defaults to 8MB.

With InnoDB, simply use autocommit=1 to get each IODKU committed as you go.

Summary:  For performance, use IODKU and build the string until you get to, say, 7MB or 1000 rows, whichever comes first.

Much of this is mentioned in [Rick's Rules of Thumb](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots).